# Subpabase (nextjs) querying multi level/relational tables returning null value

Tags: postgresql, next.js, supabase

I have three tables
1->profiles (auth.id (FK from auth.user table), username, useremail)
2->posts (post_id, user_id (FK from profile table, post_text))
3->post_replies(reply_id, user_id (FK from profile table), post_id (FK from posts table), reply_text)

This is my query

```
const { data: posts } = await supabase.from('posts').select('* ,profiles(username, useremail)
```

This works fine if there is no relationship between "**posts**" and the "**post_replies**" tables,  as soon as I add the relationship (**posts->post_replies**), it starts returning "null" value even I have not included **post_replies** in the query,

I have tried disabling RLS but no luck, as soon as I remove the relation (**posts->post_replies**) it start returing the data.

Can anyone please help to point me on right direction, what I am doing wrong here?

I have tried different way of changing the query, disabling RLS, tried SQL (in sql editor) which works fine with all roles. Its only nextjs query returns null.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the **public.profiles** relationship with the **auth.user** table and the query starts working.
It looks like you cannot have more than one level relationship across schemas(in this case, **auth** and **public** schemas).